# Why some shells `read` builtin fail to read the whole line from file in `/proc`?

Tags: linux, shell, proc, read

In some Bourne-like shells, the `read` builtin can not read the whole line from file in `/proc` (the command below should be run in `zsh`, replace `$=shell` with `$shell` with other shells):

```
$ for shell in bash dash ksh mksh yash zsh schily-sh heirloom-sh "busybox sh"; do
  printf '[%s]\n' "$shell"
  $=shell -c 'IFS= read x </proc/sys/fs/file-max; echo "$x"'       
done
[bash]
602160
[dash]
6
[ksh]
602160
[mksh]
6
[yash]
6
[zsh]
6
[schily-sh]
602160
[heirloom-sh]
602160
[busybox sh]
6
```

[`read` standard requires the standard input need to be a text file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html#tag_20_109_06), does that requirement cause the varied behaviors?

---

Read the POSIX definition of [text file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_397), I do some verification:

```
$ od -t a </proc/sys/fs/file-max 
0000000   6   0   2   1   6   0  nl
0000007

$ find /proc/sys/fs -type f -name 'file-max'
/proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

There's no `NUL` character in content of `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`, and also `find` reported it as a regular file (Is this a bug in `find`?).

I guess the shell did something under the hood, like `file`:

```
$ file /proc/sys/fs/file-max
/proc/sys/fs/file-max: empty
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that those `/proc` files on Linux appear as text files as far as `stat()/fstat()` is concerned, but do not behave as such.

Because it's dynamic data, you can only do one `read()` system call on them (for some of them at least). Doing more than one could get you two chunks of two different contents, so instead it seems a second `read()` on them just returns nothing (meaning end-of-file) (unless you `lseek()` back to the beginning (and to the beginning only)).

The `read` utility needs to read the content of files one byte at a time to be sure not to read past the newline character. That's what `dash` does:

```
 $ strace -fe read dash -c 'read a < /proc/sys/fs/file-max'
 read(0, "1", 1)                         = 1
 read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
```

Some shells like `bash` have an optimisation to avoid having to do so many `read()` system calls. They first check whether the file is seekable, and if so, read in chunks as then they know they can put the cursor back just after the newline if they've read past it:

```
$ strace -e lseek,read bash -c 'read a' < /proc/sys/fs/file-max
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(0, "1628689\n", 128)               = 8
```

With `bash`, you'd still have problems for proc files that are more than 128 bytes large and can only be read in one read system call.

`bash` also seems to disable that optimization when the `-d` option is used.

`ksh93` takes the optimisation even further so much as to become bogus. ksh93's `read` does seek back, but remembers the extra data it has read for the next `read`, so the next `read` (or any of its other builtins that read data like `cat` or `head`) doesn't even try to `read` the data (even if that data has been modified by other commands in between):

```
$ seq 10 > a; ksh -c 'read a; echo test > a; read b; echo "$a $b"' < a
1 2
$ seq 10 > a; sh -c 'read a; echo test > a; read b; echo "$a $b"' < a
1 st
```

Comment: Ah yes, an `strace`-based explanation is much easier to understand!

Comment: Thanks, *dynamic data* make sense. So how does the shell detect it's dynamic data? If I do `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max | ...`, the problem gone.

Comment: The shell doesn't detect it. The fact that it's dynamic data means that `procfs` can't handle multiple successive `read(2)` calls to the same file; the behaviour doesn't depend on the shell. Using `cat` and piping works because `cat` reads the file in large enough chunks; the shell's `read` built-in then reads from the pipe one character at a time.

Comment: Interresting... I'm surprised there is no need for "IFS= read -r" instead of a simple "read" ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, you generally need `IFS=` and `-r`, but not here to demonstrate this issue.

Comment: There is a bit dirty workaround in `mksh`. `read -N 10 a < /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Comment: @IporSircer. Indeed. A similar work around seems to work with `zsh`: `read -u0 -k10` (or use `sysread`; `$mapfile[/proc/sys/fs/file-max]` doesn't work as those files can't be `mmap`ed). In any case, with any shell, one can always to `a=$(cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max)`. With some including `mksh`, `zsh` and `ksh93`, `a=$(</proc/sys/fs/file-max)` also works and does not fork a process to do the reading.

Answer (score 11):

If you are interested in knowing **why?** this is so, you can see the
answer in the kernel sources [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L2344):

```
    if (!data || !table->maxlen || !*lenp || (*ppos && !write)) {
            *lenp = 0;
            return 0;
    }
```

Basically, seeking (`*ppos` not 0) is not implemented for reads (`!write`)
of sysctl values that are numbers.  Whenever a read is done from `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`,
the routine in question
`__do_proc_doulongvec_minmax()` is called from the entry for `file-max` in
the configuration [table](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L1619) in
the same file.

Other entries, such as `/proc/sys/kernel/poweroff_cmd` are implemented via
`proc_dostring()` which does allow seeks, so you can do `dd bs=1` on it and read from your shell with no problems.

Note that since kernel 2.6 most `/proc` reads were implemented via a new API
called
[seq_file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt)
and this supports seeks so eg reading `/proc/stat` should not cause
problems. The `/proc/sys/` implementation, as we can see, does not use this
api.

Answer (score 4):

On the first attempt, this looks like a bug in the shells that return less than a real Bourne Shell or its derivatives return (sh, bosh, ksh, heirloom).

The original Bourne Shell tries to read a block (64 bytes) newer Bourne Shell variants read 128 bytes, but they start reading again if there is no new line character.

Background: /procfs and similar implementations (e.g. the mounted `/etc/mtab` virtual file) have dynamic content and a `stat()` call does not cause the **re-creation** of the dynamic content first. For this reason, the size of such a file (from reading until EOF) may differ from what `stat()` returns.

Given that the POSIX standard requires utilities to expect *short reads* at any time, software that believes that a `read()` that returns less than the *ordered* amount of bytes is an EOF indication are broken. A correctly implemented utility calls `read()` a second time in case that it returns less than expected - until a 0 is returned. In case of the `read` builtin, it would of course be sufficient to read until `EOF` **or** until a `NL` is seen.

If you run `truss` or a truss clone, you should be able to verify that incorrect behavior for the shells that only return `6` in your experiment.

In this special case, it seems to be a Linux kernel bug, see:

```
$ sdd -debug bs=1 if= /proc/sys/fs/file-max 
Simple copy ...
readbuf  (3, 12AC000, 1) = 1
writebuf (1, 12AC000, 1)
8readbuf  (3, 12AC000, 1) = 0

sdd: Read  1 records + 0 bytes (total of 1 bytes = 0.00k).
sdd: Wrote 1 records + 0 bytes (total of 1 bytes = 0.00k).
```

The Linux kernel returns **0** with the second `read` and this is of course incorrect.

Conclusion: Shells that first try to read a large enough chunk of data do not trigger this Linux kernel bug.

Comment: OK, exited answer with a new verification for a Linux kernel bug.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: This is a really strange claim.

Comment: It would be a feature if it were documented. Reading https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt, I see no documentation for the behavior. That said, it's clearly working-as-intended-by-the-implementor, so if this is to be considered a bug, it's bug in the design, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The files under /proc sometimes use NULL character to separate fields inside the file. It seems that read is not able to handle this.